# How to parse throught a timestamp value and change timestamp values

Tags: pyspark, timestamp, unix-timestamp

Given this timestamp value *2019-01-29T16:22:54+00:00* (in this format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss±hh:mm)

I need to change the last 00:00 (corresponding to hh:mm) into a 'Z'

Comment: So. What is stopping you?

Comment: i dont know how to do it basically , i should find a wayt ot parse throught the date check if hh:mm is equal to 00:00 and if its true change with the letter 'Z'

Comment: So, you are in python, and you have this date as string, right? Have you thought about replacing the last 6 chars with "Z" ? `myVar = '2019-01-29T16:22:54+00:00';
print( myVar[:19] + "Z" );` worked in my playground.

Comment: Is that a dataframe? Please add the output of df.printSchema() to your question.

Comment: yea is a dataframe with a column Time that contains timestamp date in this format 2019-01-29T16:22:54+00:00 . but everytime there's the +00:00 i need to replace that with a Z.

Comment: Could you please add the requested output: df.printSchema() to your initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check simple sample below, you can adjust it for your more requirement

```
def convert_z_time(time_string):
    if time_string[-5:] == '00:00':
        converted_time = '{}Z'.format(time_string[:-6])
    else:
        converted_time = time_string
    return converted_time


time_string = '2019-01-29T16:22:54+00:00'    
print(convert_z_time(time_string))

time_string = '2019-01-29T16:22:54+10:00'    
print(convert_z_time(time_string))
```

The output should be

```
2019-01-29T16:22:54Z
2019-01-29T16:22:54+10:00
```

Hope it works for you